# Using loop to highlight current half-hour in table

Tags: javascript, loops, calendar

I need help using a loop to highlight the current half-hour in the calendar. The shorter the code, the better. However, the whole row is not highlighted but just the cell that's the current day of the week and half hour, and it needs to be highlighted in a different color than the week column that's highlighted.
This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>December</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>December Calender</h1>


    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="sun" id="sunday">sun</th>
            <th class="mon" id="monday">mon</th>
            <th class="tue" id="tuesday">tue</th>
            <th class="wed" id="wensday">wed</th>
            <th class="thu" id="thursday">thu</th>
            <th class="fri" id="friday">fri</th>
            <th class="sat" id="saturday">sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">8:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">8:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">9:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">9:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">10:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">10:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">11:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">11:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">12:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">12:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">1:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">1:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">2:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">2:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">3:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">3:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">4:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">4:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">5:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">5:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">6:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">6:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">7:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">7:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">8:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
   let today = new Date();
        switch (today.getDay()) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("sunday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var sun = document.getElementsByClassName('sun');
                for (var i = 0; i < sun.length; i++) {
                    sun[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("monday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var mon = document.getElementsByClassName('mon');
                for (var i = 0; i < mon.length; i++) {
                    mon[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("tuesday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var tue = document.getElementsByClassName('tue');
                for (var i = 0; i < tue.length; i++) {
                    tue[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("wensday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var wed = document.getElementsByClassName('wed');
                for (var i = 0; i < wed.length; i++) {
                    wed[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("thursday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var thu = document.getElementsByClassName('thu');
                for (var i = 0; i < thu.length; i++) {
                    thu[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("friday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var fri = document.getElementsByClassName('fri');
                for (var i = 0; i < fri.length; i++) {
                    fri[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("saturday").style.backgroundColor = "#b19cd9";
                var sat = document.getElementsByClassName('sat');
                for (var i = 0; i < sat.length; i++) {
                    sat[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';

                }
                break;
        }
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by applying this working code to create your calendar in a loop:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // create p-element with text content
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("Some text here");
    para.appendChild(node);

    // add attribute to p-element
    para.setAttribute("style", "color:#2b9"+i+";");

    // append element to existing dom
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
    <div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Codepen: https://codepen.io/wordswithchung/pen/OJPbOXK

```js
const times = [
'8:00 AM',
'8:30 AM',
'9:00 AM',
'9:30 AM',
'10:00 AM',
'10:30 AM',
'11:00 AM',
'11:30 AM',
'12:00 PM',
'12:30 PM',
'1:00 PM',
'1:30 PM',
'2:00 PM',
'2:30 PM',
'3:00 PM',
'3:30 PM',
'4:00 PM',
'4:30 PM',
'5:00 PM',
'5:30 PM',
'6:00 PM',
'6:30 PM',
'7:00 PM',
'7:30 PM',
'8:00 PM'];
const dayClasses = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

const myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

// get the current date value; ultimate goal is to make a string of the current date
// that resembles something in our times array
const currentDate = new Date();
const currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
const currentMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes() < 30 ? 00 : 30;
const isPM = currentHour >= 12;
// take the current time and transform it into a string that resembles one of the 
// options in the times array (e.g., '8:00 PM') precisely for comparison later
const currentTime = `${isPM ? currentHour - 12 : currentHour}:${currentMinutes} ${isPM ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`;

for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
  // determine if we should highlight this row
  const isCurrentTime = times[i] == currentTime;
  // create row
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  // create the column that displays the current time
  const dateColumn = document.createElement('td');
  dateColumn.className = "date";
  dateColumn.innerText = times[i];
  row.appendChild(dateColumn);
  // create the columns for the days
  dayClasses.forEach((day) => {
    const newColumn = document.createElement('td');
    newColumn.className = day;
    if (isCurrentTime) {
      // if it's the current time, add the nice background color to highlight it
      newColumn.style.backgroundColor = '#00FFFF';
    }
    row.appendChild(newColumn);
  })
  myTable.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>December</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>December Calendar</h1>


    <table class="tg" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="sun" id="sunday">sun</th>
            <th class="mon" id="monday">mon</th>
            <th class="tue" id="tuesday">tue</th>
            <th class="wed" id="wensday">wed</th>
            <th class="thu" id="thursday">thu</th>
            <th class="fri" id="friday">fri</th>
            <th class="sat" id="saturday">sat</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[Output from the code on Codepen; the row for the current time has the cyan background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEXjE.png)

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hello, for some reason the row for the current time doesn't show up in cyan background color, or any color at all.

Comment: I clicked on the "Run code snippet" button in stack overflow and it seems to be working as expected: it's 10:58 AM PT and the 10:30 AM row has cyan background color across all 7 days. What are you seeing?